# Binary structure for a directory with files

Tags: file, header, directory, byte, serialization

I'm trying to solve the following problem. I want to create a set of directories with files in them , but *in memory* using C# , using strings / byte arrays, and I am trying to figure out what's the format and byte sequence for all of this. i mean something like

`<magic sequence for top directory header> <magic sequence for file header> </ end file> ... file 2 file 3 ... etc ... </magic sequence for the directory header> , etc.`

I'm talking about windows formats here.

Could you point me to a location where i can read about this or even better, give me some existing examples?

Thanks !
Angel

Comment: So you want to create some kind of ISO file format?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking depends on the filesystem in use. The filesystem defines how files and directories are stored. On windows a common format is [FAT32](http://www.pjrc.com/tech/8051/ide/fat32.html) and NTFS (which is not publically available).

As shown in the link above, the FAT format is [specified](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/platform/firmware/fatgen.mspx) by Microsoft